# How to create a "manager" for many steps algorithms in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm implementing an encoding algorithm which involves many different classes at each step. Something like:

```
void MagicAlgorithm(Class1 c1, Class2 c2, ..., Classn cn){
    //step 1
    c1.doSomething();
    //step 2
    c2.doSomething();
    ...
    //step n
    cn.doSomething();
}
```

All these `n` classes are abstracts and different implementations are used for performance comparison. Notice that the order of the methods calling is important.

I'm defining `MagicAlgorithm` since `n` is large and the user could call `doSomething()` in the wrong order. So `MagicAlgorithm` does the dirty work for the user in the right order.

However, nothing stops the user to call `doSomething` outiside of `MagicAlgorithm` (it just need to instatiate `Classk ck` and then call `ck.doSomething()`). This is something that I would like to avoid.

Is it possible to call `doSomething()` only inside `MagicAlgorithm()` and not outside of it?

Comment: Don't try to avoid too much stuff. The user still needs to read the documentation and use classes in an appropriate way.  Maybe the user knows what he's doing, and he wants to call `.doSomething()` in some other order, to accomplish something different you didn't think about. You could make it friends, but these are abstract classes, which means the user can give you anything he wants anyway. So, what would be the purpose of hiding from the user functions the user can define?

Comment: Well these are abstract classes because I give a set of different implementations to the user, so he can chose which implementations he prefers and then exploiting polymorphism calling `doSomething()` without caring the actual implementation. Well he could give its own implementation of the abstract class, but that's something that would be "unexpected" from me as the designer of the library. However I get your point.

Comment: But then, why don't you ask for enums, rather than classes? If the classes you're using as arguments do not hold a user-customizable state, and you're only using them for the virtual .doSomething() (btw, you have to take them by reference, or the polymorphism doesn't work), then you may as well take N different enums, and then have private switch functions that map enum values to functions that do the job. Runtime-wise, it should be as fast as calling a virtual function (in both cases, you have to access an entry of a table that contains the address of the function to call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `doSomething` methods private and add

```
friend MagicAlgorithm(Class1, Class2, ..., Classn);
```

to the relevant class declarations. When made `friend` like this, `MagicAlgorithm` can then call private functions of the classes.

---

You probably want to change the function signature to use references or pointers (`const` if `doSomething` is `const`, but it probably isn't):

```
void MagicAlgorithm(Class1&, Class2&, ..., Classn&);
```

Because then it is enough to forward declare (`class Class1; class Class2; ... class Classn;`) all the classes, and you avoid the n eed to include everything in every .h file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion, never heard about `friend` functions! But what if `MagicAlgorithm` is a method of a class `MagicClass`?

Comment: You can also make classes friend. I'll edit the question later to include some links, but you should be able to google the details.